# ViewPager taking onClick events from parent?

Tags: android

I have a layout like:

```
<LinearLayout id="@+id/parent" clickable="true">
  <ViewPager />
</LinearLayout>
```

and a click listener on the parent. But it doesn't response to click events. It seems that the viewpager takes them. Is there a way to have the parent handle the click events?

Thanks

Comment: `LinearLayout` is not clickable by default. Try to add `android:clickable=true`

Answer (score -1):

```
final View myview2;
View view=(View) myViewPager.findViewById(position);
myview2 = (View) ((ViewGroup) view).getParent();


if (myview2 instanceof LinearLayout) {
Log.d("instanceof", "linearLayout");
}
```

use that if you get the view as instanceof `LinearLayout` add clicklistener there for `myview2`
see here for more about `getParent();`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#getParent()

If the `LinearLayout` is a *rootview* then you can use:

```
View view=findViewById(R.id.main);
View v1 = view.getRootView();
```

If you are conserned about the `Views` inside the `ViewPager` then you can modify `getParent()` to `getChildAt(0)`.

and you can also use :
`myLinearLayout.bringToFront();`

Comment: Hi sorry I don't follow - I want to add the click listener to the layout with id="parent". It's not clear to me which of the above should be used for that?

Comment: try using `yourlinearlayout.bringToFront();` and then the click Listener must work